# Open NavigationView on Right Swipe from everywhere on the layout

Tags: android, navigationview

I would like to open the navigationview on a right swipe, no matter where the right swipe is. Default you have to make the right swipe quite at the side, but I want to swipe for example from the middle to open the navigationview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could either increase the swipe edge of the drawer using something like this

```
public static void increaseSwipeEdgeOfDrawer(DrawerLayout mDlSearchDrawer) {
        try {

            Field mDragger = mDlSearchDrawer.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                    "mRightDragger");//mRightDragger or mLeftDragger based on Drawer Gravity
            mDragger.setAccessible(true);
            ViewDragHelper draggerObj = (ViewDragHelper) mDragger
                    .get(mDlSearchDrawer);

            Field mEdgeSize = draggerObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                    "mEdgeSize");
            mEdgeSize.setAccessible(true);
            int edge = mEdgeSize.getInt(draggerObj);


            mEdgeSize.setInt(draggerObj, <size of the edge here>);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

or you could give keep a view on top that matches the size of the drawer layout, assign on on tough listener to it to detect a swipe and call [DrawerLayout#openDrawer(android.view.View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(android.view.View)) on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to `@override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and can detect right swipe in your drawer activity, then open drawer in that.

```html
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{     
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          x1 = event.getX();                         
      break;         
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          x2 = event.getX();
          float deltaX = x2 - x1;

          if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
          {
              // Left to Right swipe action
              if (x2 > x1)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right swipe [Next]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();   
                  drawer.openDrawer();     //OPEN YOUR DRAWER HERE              
              }

          }
          else
          {
              // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
          }                          
      break;   
    }           
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);       
}
```

Comment: What is x2 and x1 in your case?

Comment: temp Float Variable, not initialized with any value.