# How can I swipe from left to right at anywhere to open a drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, slidingdrawer

I'm very new to code, and I met a lot of problems while building my first app.
I want to create a drawer that I can swipe from left to right from anywhere to open. (not swipe from the edge)
so the component tree of my MainActivity view is:

- DrawerLayout

  - Navigationview (drawer layout)
  - ConstraintLayout (mainpage layout)

THIS IS MainActivity.Java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;




public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureObject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gestureObject = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new LearnGesture());


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.gestureObject.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private class LearnGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            if (event2.getX() > event1.getX()) {

            }



             else if (event2.getX() < event1.getX()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MainActivity.this, UpcomingActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in,R.anim.left_out);
            }
            return true;
        }


    }

}
```

This is AndroidManifest.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UpcomingActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_upcoming"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the code can run but has following render problems:

1.using the design library requires using Theme.AppCompat or a desecendant
(Select Theme.AppCompat or a desecendant in the theme selector.)
2.Failed to instantiate one or more classes

Actually I even not so sure if I'm in the right direction, I don't know whether I should use fragment or drawerlayout to complete this activity ?
Can somebody do me a favor or share with me some related tutorials?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this will be useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17815915/6630837

Comment: refer this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34878107/6630837